# Creating a class in Corona sdk and dispatching events from it?

Tags: oop, lua, coronasdk

I want to make a class, that holds some graphics and dispatch events from this class when a button is tapped... here is my simple code:

MyClass.lua:

```
local Class = {}
local Class_mt = { __index = Class }    -- metatable
local thisObject

-------------------------------------------------
-- PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
-------------------------------------------------

local function tapListener( e )    -- local; only visible in this module
    local event = {
        name = "customEvent",
        mycustomvar = "this is my custom var"
    }

    thisObject.body:dispatchEvent( event )
end

-------------------------------------------------
-- PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
-------------------------------------------------

function Class.new( )    -- constructor

    local rect = display.newRect( 0, 0, 50, 50 )
    rect:addEventListener( "tap", tapListener )

    local newClass = {
        body = rect
    }

    return setmetatable( newClass, Class_mt )
end


-- added this function to get reference to the object
function Class:init()
    thisObject = self
end
-------------------------------------------------

return Class
```

and then create this class and listen to some events being dispached:

```
local MyClass = require( "MyClass" )

function myCustomEvent(e)
  print(e.mycustomvar)
end

local myNewClass = MyClass.new()
myNewClass:init()
myNewClass.body:addEventListener("customEvent", myCustomEvent)
```

This does work .. but seems kinda hacky - please tell me what you think?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained on http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/EventListener/dispatchEvent.html, the dispatchEvent is a method of a display object. So you can't call it on your Class, because class is just a table representing a "Class" class (you should probably name it something else ;) So you would call dispatchEvent on the rect (if it represents a custom event that occured in the rect), or from the runtime (if it represents an "application" event). If custom event is for the rect, and since the event listener callbacks only take parameter (the event), you should inlude a "target" member in your custom event in case the listener wants to know which "rect" sent the event.

```
local function tapListener( e )    -- local; only visible in this module
    local event = {
        name = "customEvent",
        myscustomvar = "this is my custom var",
        target = rect
    }
    rect:dispatchEvent( event )
end
```

Notice how you use rect in tapListener, so that function needs access to rect. Probably best to put the tapListener inside the Class.new():

```
function Class.new( )    -- constructor

    local rect = display.newRect( 0, 0, 50, 50 )

    local function tapListener( e )    -- local; only visible in this module
        local event = {
            name = "customEvent",
            myscustomvar = "this is my custom var",
            target = rect
        }
        rect:dispatchEvent( event )
    end

    rect:addEventListener( "tap", tapListener )

    ...
end
```

If you don't like to create functions in the contructor, there are other ways, they each have different advantages and disadvantages. I personally like to keep things together so I would favor the above. You could also move the various handlers (like tapListener) to a "listener factory" function like this:

```
function bindCustomEventDispatcher(rect)
    local function tapListener(e) 
        local event = { ... } -- create custom event
        rect:dispatchEvent( event )
    end
    local function touchListener(e) 
        local event = { ... } -- create custom event
        rect:dispatchEvent( event )
    end
    local function zapListener(e) 
        local event = { ... } -- create custom event
        rect:dispatchEvent( event )
    end
    rect:addEventListener( "tap", tapListener )
    rect:addEventListener( "touch", touchListener )
    rect:addEventListener( "zap", zapListener )
end
```

I didn't suggest using module-global variable as it doesn't scale as easily to more than one object (rect instance), you would have to use an array. But if that is not a concern then your approach is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer.... still if I would need to dispatch several events... then they would all end up cramped in the constructor... I updated my question and got it to work avoiding bunch of local functions inside constructor... What you think of "my way"?

Comment: Perfectly valid, I expanded my answer to explain why I didn't suggest it and an alternative that you might prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed the code. Now it should work.

MyClass.lua:

```
local Class = {}
local Class_mt = { __index = Class }    -- metatable

-------------------------------------------------
-- PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
-------------------------------------------------


local function tapListener( e )    -- local; only visible in this module
    local event = {
        name = "customEvent",
        myscustomvar = "this is my custom var"
    }
    Runtime:dispatchEvent( event )
end

-------------------------------------------------
-- PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
-------------------------------------------------

function Class.new( )    -- constructor

    local rect = display.newRect( 0, 0, 50, 50 )
    rect:addEventListener( "tap", tapListener )


    local newClass = {
        body = rect
    }

    return setmetatable( newClass, Class_mt )
end

-------------------------------------------------

return Class
```

main.lua

```
local MyClass = require( "MyClass" )
local mynewclass = MyClass.new()

local function myCustomEvent(e)
    print(e.myscustomvar)
end

Runtime:addEventListener("customEvent", myCustomEvent)
```

Comment: I updated my question - pls see above - I made it work. What if I wanted to dispatch events from the instance of the class instead of Runtime? Thanks.